# Setting initial height for constraint-animated UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I want to animate a view (the green one in the screenshots) from it's bottom up to a height defined by proximity to the Top Layout Guide. My plan is to animate the vertical distance constraint (top of green box to Top Layout Guide), like so:

[image] [image]

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)upButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.animatedHeightConstraint.constant = 20;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

Fine, this works.

However, this scheme doesn't take into account the starting height of the view, which I want to be very small, probably zero. But since at this point I'm relying on the constant set in the Storyboard to set the starting height, the constant can be any number, depending on the device.

I need a positive method to set an initial, device-independent starting point for the top of the green UIView.

My first thought was to set a Height constraint, but the compiler detects the conflict, and corrects by breaking the restraint.

My second thought, although it seems pretty clumsy, is to set both constraints, then remove the Vertical constraint at runtime, then immediately remove the Height constraint and add back the Vertical constraint.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there really no more elegant way to go about this?

**Update:**

Since I haven't received an answer yet, I tried implementing my second thought, detailed above. I added an `initialHeightConstraint` to the green bar via this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.animatedHeightConstraint];
    [self.greenBar addConstraint:self.initialHeightConstraint];

    self.initialHeightConstraint.constant = 1;
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];

}
```

This works. The `greenBar` is set to the desired height, which is different from the `constant` in the Soryboard:

[image]

Next, I try to swap out the two constraints and animate the `animatedHeightConstraint`:

```
- (IBAction)upButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.greenBar removeConstraint:self.initialHeightConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.animatedHeightConstraint];

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];


    self.animatedHeightConstraint.constant = 20;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

This doesn't work. Crashes with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: [constraint isKindOfClass:[NSLayoutConstraint class]]'
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand what this means. Could use some help!

Comment: Set a lower priority for the green view's height constraint and a higher priority constraint relating its top to the container? Alternatively adjust content hugging/restriction?

Comment: I just tried this--doesn't seem to have any effect. I first tried lowering it to 500, then to 1. No dice either way. I may be using it wrong, though. My first time.

Comment: Why don't you add this constraint in code itself and then change its constant when required.

Comment: @jarora--Isn't that what I'm doing here?